# Non-regular Continuous-Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a Continuous-Time Markov Chain (CTMC) with $P_{i,i+1}=1$ and $v_i=i^2$. Here, $P_{i,i+1}$ is the probability of jumping from state $i$ to state $i+1$, and $v_i$ is the rate of holding times. We know a regular CTMC is defined to be a CTMC such that with probability $1$, the number of jumps in any finite time interval is finite. Prove that the above CTMC is not regular.
I appreciate any comment/hint.

*my attempt: I want to use the fact that the holding time in state $i$, denoted by $\tau_i$ has an exponential distribution with rate $v_i$. Now, consider the interval $[0,t]$. The probability that the number of jumps is finite (say less than a finite number $n$) is equivalent to the probability that that $\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i > t$. Now, $\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i$ is the sum of exponential random variables with rates $v_i$. I need to find the pdf of $\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i$. I do not know how to proceed.*

Comment: You could show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\tau_i<\infty$ with probability 1. One way to do that is to show that 
$$
\Bbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^\infty\tau_i\right]<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks John. If the expectation of a random variable is bounded, it is always true that the random variable itself is also bounded?

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable with values in $[0,+\infty]$ and finite expectation $\mu$, then Markov's inequality tells us that
$$
\Bbb P[X>t]\le{\mu\over t},\qquad t>0.
$$
In particular (let $t\to+\infty$): $\Bbb P[X=+\infty] = 0$, so that $\Bbb P[X<+\infty] = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by John Dawkins, we can show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tau_i < \infty$. Note that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tau_i] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\tau_i] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty.
\end{align}
Since the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tau_i] $ is finite, we have $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tau_i < \infty) = 1$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: Careful with your terminology: *bounded* would mean there was a *constant* $M>0$ such that $\Bbb P\left[\sum_i\tau_i\le M\right]=1$. The finite-expectation only shows that $\Bbb P\left[\sum_i\tau_i<+\infty\right]=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.